# Android 13 read/import client certificate as p12-file

Tags: android, client-certificates, android-13

How can I read/import in Android 13 an own client certificate as p12 file?

I copied it over the "file manager"-App to the Documents directory and then tried to read the p12-file without success.
I am getting:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/Documents/xxxx/client2.p12: open failed: EACCES
> (Permission denied)

I tried with Filereader, InputStream but no chance.
I know, that with Android 13 I don't need the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

How can I import the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Has nothing to do with the type of the file.

Its just that the file is not created by your app that you have no acces on an Android 11+ device.

Try File.exists() and File.canRead() before you try to read.

You can import the file by letting the user choose it with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or ACTION_GET_CONTENT.